# How can i set titlebar in middle?

Tags: java, android

i want to set my tittle bar in center (i mean just text) and i don't want to use `Style` and `Layout` , now which method can i use?
Thank you

Comment: AFAIK, this can't be achieved without using layouts. If you have a root layout of your TextView, you can set its android:layout_gravity="center" to center it on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just using `setGravity` , it's easy to use through Layouts.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Cutsom Title [(here)](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/CustomTitle.html) example in the SDK, it should help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);`